# Parsing df -k output to get the utilisation details

Tags: parsing, sed

The specific problem that motivates the question is, I'm writing a bash script to check disk utilisation with `df -k` and want the script to do something when utilisation exceeds a threshold, say, 90%.

So I'm getting a line like:

```
/dev/xvda1       8376300 7611164    765136  91% /
```

How to get the part with the 91%? It looks to me that we can break down the line into chunks of non-whitespace followed by chunks of whitespace, and this pattern repeats, with the last occurrence containing the 91%, i.e., "91% ". Indeed, when I use regex101.com and I put in

```
([^\s]+[\s]+)+
```

it gives a promising looking result:
[image]

In particular, it was great to see

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

As regex101.com was saying I had specified a repeated capturing group, and only the last one, "91% ", would be returned as `Group 1`. Perfect.

However, when I went to use this regex in bash to extract the desired portion, it somehow gave the whole line as output.

```
$ df -k | grep xvda1 | sed "s/\([^\s]+[\s]+\)+/\1/"
/dev/xvda1       8376300 7610788    765512  91% /
```

Any idea what went wrong? Is it that bash's implementation of regex (ERE [supposedly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15481/what-regular-expression-engine-type-does-bash-use)) just doesn't follow this behavior of capturing the last capture group of a repeated capturing group? In regex101.com, there is no ERE option, so I tried with PCRE and PCRE2 and both gave the same results.

Comment: bash isn't using a regexp in your code, sed is, and what sed does with a regexp is as completely unrelated to what bash does as it would be if you were using C or python or any other tool to evaluate the regexp. If you had `if [[ $var ~= ([^\s]+[\s]+)+ ]]; then ...` or similar THEN it'd be bash's implementation of a regexp you'd have to consider as then it'd be bash evaluating that regexp, not sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is not needed here and it will add not needed complexity. So, unless you really want to do it via regex just take the "Use" column and work with it. Then cleanup the % and you're good to go.

```
zca@elitedesk:~$ df -k | awk '{print $5}'
Use%
1%
24%
0%
0%
28%
2%
3%
1%
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with `df -k | grep xvda1 |  awk '{print $5}'` and just needed to remove the % after that.

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
$ df --help
...
 --output[=FIELD_LIST]  use the output format defined by FIELD_LIST,
                        or print all fields if FIELD_LIST is omitted.
...

$ man df
...
 FIELD_LIST is a comma-separated list of columns to be included.  
 Valid field names are: 
    'source', 'fstype', 'itotal', 'iused', 'iavail', 
    'ipcent', 'size', 'used', 'avail',  'pcent',
    'file' and 'target' (see info page).
...

$ df -k --output=pcent
Use%
  0%
  1%
 90%
  7%
  1%
  0%
 47%
 12%
  2%
 83%
  1%
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En '/xvda1/{s~[^/]* ([0-9]+%).*~\1~p}' <(df -k)
```

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i=="Use%") u=i} $NF=="/" {print $u}' <(df -k)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
df -k | sed -nE '/xvda1/s/^((\S+)\s+){5}.*/\2/p'
```

This returns the fifth non whitespaced column (`\2`) of a line containing `xvda1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example `[[:space:]]` and the negated version `[^[:space:]]` instead of `\s`

Escape the quantifier `\+` and if you don't want the `/` at the end you can match the rest

**Note** that there is a trailing space in the capture group 1 value just as in your screenshot.

```
df -k | grep "xvda1" | sed "s/\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\+.*/\1/"
```

*Output:*

`91%`

---

You could also make the pattern more specific capturing the digits in group 1 followed by matching the `%` and `/` if you only want the digits:

```
sed "s/.*[[:space:]]\([[:digit:]]\+\)%[[:space:]]\+\/$/\1/"
```

*Output:*

`91`

---

An alternative for the digits only using `gnu-awk`, capturing the digits in group 1 followed by matching `%`

```
df -k | grep "xvda1" | awk 'match($5, /^([0-9]+)%$/, a) {print a[1]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You never need grep when you're using awk, e.g. `grep xvda1 |  awk '{print $5}'` = `awk '/xvda1/{print $5}'` and you don't need another step to remove the `%`, just have awk do that too. All you need is:

```
df -k | awk '/xvda1/{print $5+0}'
```

and if you're writing a shell script to do something when that value gets over 90, all you need is:

```
if df -k | awk '/xvda1/{exit ($5+0 <= 90)}; then
    echo "the sky is falling"
fi
```

For example:

```
$ if echo '/dev/xvda1       8376300 7611164    765136  91% /' |
    awk '/xvda1/{exit ($5+0 <= 90)}'; then echo "the sky is falling"; fi
the sky is falling
$
```

```
$ if echo '/dev/xvda1       8376300 7611164    765136  90% /' |
    awk '/xvda1/{exit ($5+0 <= 90)}'; then echo "the sky is falling"; fi
$
```